# How to make program compile while using modulus to convert decimal value into currency?

Tags: c++, decimal, modulus

I don't know how to make my program compile, I'm new at programming.

I would like to know if I can compile just by adapting `printf` or if I need some other function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int V = 0;
    scanf("%d", &V);
    printf("NOTAS: \n");
    printf("%d Nota(s) de R$ 100.00\n", V / 100);
    printf("%d Nota(s) de R$ 50.00\n", V % 100 / 50);
    printf("%d Nota(s) de R$ 20.00\n", V % 100 % 50 / 20);
    printf("%d Nota(s) de R$ 10.00\n", V % 100 % 50 % 20 / 10);
    printf("%d Nota(s) de R$ 5.00\n", V % 100 % 50 % 20 % 10 / 5);
    printf("%d Nota(s) de R$ 2.00\n", V % 100 % 50 % 20 % 10 % 5 / 2);

    printf("MOEDAS: \n");
    printf("%d Moeda(s) de R$ 1.00\n", V % 100 % 50 % 20 % 10 % 2 / 1);
    printf("%.2lf Moeda(s) de R$ 0.50\n", V % 100 % 50 % 20 % 10 % 2 % 1 / 0.50);
    printf("%.2lf Moeda(s) de R$ 0.25\n", V % 100 % 50 % 20 % 10 % 2 % 1 % 0.50 / 0.25);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Hello Secchi! Welcome to Stackoverflow! An exact, specific error message you get during compilation would be helpful. If this compiles, a description of expected output vs. observed output would be helpful. Also, pick one language: C or C++. You have `#include <iostream>` but you're not using anything from `<iostream>`. Do you have to use `printf` or can you use `std::cout`, which would make this C++.

Comment: Don't forget `-ltsdc++` or have a `Makefile` or build script with the appropriate linker options.

Comment: @HumbertoGomes: While this site requires that post titles and body text be in English, it's not relevant to code. It would be ridiculous to expect people to rename variables and translate string literals to post here - we ask them to copy/paste actual code into their posts. [es.so] and [pt.so] are for posts where the user is more comfortable witing the question itself in another language. Code should NOT be changed for this site.

Comment: @SecchiZ edit your question showing at least the line that shows the error along with your compiler, otherwise your question doesn't make sense. Ps: fixing also code indentation would be great.

Comment: @KenWhite sorry, I must have confused the rules of StackOverflow with ones from another forum site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the line

```
printf("%.2lf Moeda(s) de R$ 0.25\n", V % 100 % 50 % 20 % 10 % 2 % 1 % 0.50 / 0.25);
                                                                     ^^^^^^
```

You cannot use modulus with decimal value, it must be an integer.

Note that the `.50` and `.25` cannot work as intended because if you input a decimal value it'll be truncated and stored as an integer since `V` is an `int`.

One thing you can do is to parse values separately, for integer values and for decimal values and take it from there.

Something like:

[**Live sample**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZbkX1B3oqGUehOBr)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    int value[2], i = 0;
    std::string V, temp;

    getline(std::cin, V);
    std::stringstream ss(V);
    while (getline(ss, temp, '.') && i < 2) //tokenize stream by '.'
    {
        value[i++] = std::stoi(temp);       //convert to integer
    }

    printf("NOTAS: \n");                //you can replace all these with std::cout
    printf("%d Nota(s) de R$ 100.00\n", value[0] / 100);
    printf("%d Nota(s) de R$ 50.00\n", value[0] % 100 / 50);
    printf("%d Nota(s) de R$ 20.00\n", value[0] % 100 % 50 / 20);
    printf("%d Nota(s) de R$ 10.00\n", value[0] % 100 % 50 % 20 / 10);
    printf("%d Nota(s) de R$ 5.00\n", value[0] % 100 % 50 % 20 % 10 / 5);
    printf("%d Nota(s) de R$ 2.00\n", value[0] % 100 % 50 % 20 % 10 % 5 / 2);

    printf("MOEDAS: \n");
    printf("%d Moeda(s) de R$ 1.00\n", value[0] % 100 % 50 % 20 % 10 % 5 % 2);
    printf("%d Moeda(s) de R$ 0.50\n", value[1] % 100 / 50);
    printf("%d Moeda(s) de R$ 0.25\n", value[1] % 100 % 50 / 25);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::fmod` might be useful, or just store monetary amounts as an integer using the smallest unit of money.

Comment: So, the problem might actually be a division by 0?

Comment: @RobertoCaboni, no I don't think so, the value 0.50 is a double, it never gets converted to integer, so the error relates to `%` operator which does not accept double values.

Comment: @anastaciu I'll have a try as soon as possible.

Comment: Thanks!!!!! Clarified my mind.

Comment: @SecchiZ, you are welcome, don't forget to [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you think it properly answers your question.